# How to read values corresponding to a formula from excel to talend?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, talend

I have a requirement in Talend to read two columns from an xlsx file, but the problem is that one of the columns that I need is a measure whose value is supplied by another excel through a formula. So the Talend metadata is picking up the formula instead of the corresponding value. The Talend environment is hosted in Unix.

Is there any way to work around this without making any change in the input excel?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can "save as csv" (everytime before reading the xlsx) be considered as a solution?

Comment: Will saving as csv and taking tFIleInputDelimited display the values instead of the formula? If yes, then it can be tried but avoiding any manual intervention would be ideal.

Comment: just throwing an idea... Another (path of troubleshooting) is to look if talend have 'another' way of reading excel in its documentation ( to force read values instead of normal read). | I don't know talend but I know csv file doesn't support formulas

Answer (score 0):

The basic Talend components are fairly limited when it comes to dealing with Excel files.

I found it way better to use the components tFileExcel-Components by Jan Lolling : [link to the latest version](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542%252Fitems%252F2897) (30/01/2019).

One of the advantages of theses components over the classic Talend ones is that when reading a formula, the component will try to interpret it*.

*If the formula references another sheet or another file it won't work.

Comment: Agreed. If the formula references another file and that file is not available, then this 3rd party component does not read its numeric value.